# Caret: how to find the best mtry and ntree by grid search

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I try to find the best mtry and ntree by grid search, but I meet some questions
First, I try to find them like this:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
grid <- expand.grid(.mtry=1:7, ntree = seq(100,1000,100)) # my dataset has 7 features
model_rf <- train(train_x, 
                  train_y,
                  method = "rf", 
                  tuneGrid = grid,
                  trControl = train_control)
model_rf$bestTune
```

however, I get an error

```
"The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry"
```

Therefore, I have to use two steps to find them:

```
# find best mtry
grid <- expand.grid(.mtry=1:7)

model_rf <- train(train_x, 
                  train_y,
                  method = "rf", 
                  tuneGrid = grid,
                  trControl = train_control)
model_rf$bestTune

# find best ntree
ntree <- seq(100,1000,100)
accuracy <- sapply(ntree, function(ntr){
  model_rf <- train(train_x, factor(train_y), 
                    method = "rf", ntree = ntr, 
                    trControl = train_control)
  accuracy <- (predict(model_fr, test_x) == test_y) %>% mean()
  return(accuracy)
})
plot(ntree, accuracy)
```

In this process, I meet some new questions:

[1] I find that best mtry is not constant. In my case, the mtry can be 2, 4, 6, and 7. So, which "best mtry" is the best? should I run this code 1000 times and calculate the mean?

[2] generally, the best mtry should be or close to the square root of the max feature number. So, should I use the sqrt(7) directly?

[3] can I get the best mtry and ntree by one train? I must say the process is so time-consuming.

Comment: You shoud use `mtry`, not `.mtry`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to include the grid of parameters inside `sapply`.

```
ntree <- seq(100,1000,100)
accuracy <- sapply(ntree, function(ntr){
grid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:7)
model_rf <- train(train_x, factor(train_y), 
                method = "rf", ntrees = ntr, 
                trControl = train_control,
                tuneGrid = grid)
accuracy <- (predict(model_fr, test_x) == test_y) %>% mean()
return(accuracy)
})
plot(ntree, accuracy)
```

So you can tune `mtry` for each run of `ntree`.
[1] The best combination of `mtry` and `ntrees` is the one that maximises the accuracy (or minimizes the RMSE in case of regression), and you should choose that model.

[2] the square root of the max feature number is the default `mtry` values, but not necessarily is the best values. It is for this reason that you use a resampling approach to find the best value.

[3] Model tuning across multiple parameters is inherently a slow process, due to the numbers of operations involved. You can try to include the best `mtry` search within each loop of `ntrees` as shown in my example code.